# Extracting specific pathname and genes in the path from a list in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of pathways and genes(corresponding to each pathway) stored in a list taken from kegg. I want to extract the genes in a pathway using the pathway ID. How can I do it?

My list looks like this

```
head(kegg2)

$`04610`
 [1] "2"     "462"   "623"   "624"   "629"   "710"   "712"   "713"   "714"   "715"   "716"   "717"   "718"   "719"   "720"   "721"   "722"   "725"   "727"  
[20] "728"   "729"   "730"   "731"   "732"   "733"   "735"   "966"   "1361"  "1378"  "1380"  "1604"  "1675"  "2147"  "2149"  "2152"  "2153"  "2155"  "2157" 
[39] "2158"  "2159"  "2160"  "2161"  "2162"  "2165"  "2243"  "2244"  "2266"  "3053"  "3075"  "3426"  "3818"  "3827"  "4153"  "4179"  "5054"  "5104"  "5265" 
[58] "5327"  "5328"  "5329"  "5340"  "5345"  "5624"  "5627"  "5648"  "7035"  "7056"  "7450"  "10747"

$`00232`
[1] "9"    "10"   "1544" "1548" "1549" "1553" "7498"

$`00983`
 [1] "9"      "10"     "978"    "1066"   "1548"   "1549"   "1551"   "1553"   "1576"   "1577"   "1806"   "1807"   "1890"   "2990"   "3251"   "3614"   "3615"  
[18] "3704"   "7083"   "7084"   "7172"   "7363"   "7364"   "7365"   "7366"   "7367"   "7371"   "7372"   "7378"   "7498"   "8824"   "8833"   "10720"  "10941" 
[35] "51733"  "54490"  "54575"  "54576"  "54577"  "54578"  "54579"  "54600"  "54657"  "54658"  "54659"  "54963"  "64816"  "79799"  "83549"  "151531" "221223"
[52] "574537"
```

So the digits after `$` are the pathways IDs, I want to pull out the genes in a specific pathway using the pathway ID. For example, i want to pull out the the genes for pathway **00232** so i want the output be like

```
00232 [1] "9" "10" "1544" "1548" "1549" "1553" "7498"
```

Answer (score 2):

Access elements of a list with:

```
kegg2[["00232"]]
```

or (note the use of backticks ` to allow the use of a number as a "name")

```
kegg2$`00232`
```